# Jenkins without Automated Tests

Tags: java, junit, jenkins

I know that Jenkins is focused on  continous building/testing, monitoring of batch jobs  about the project. I have a legacy project which such condition :

1. Has a development team.
2. It has SVN for source code management
3. Some cronjobs for some operations.
4. Compile&Build don't take too much time, there is no very complex dependencies.
5. It doesn't have any automated test/junit classes and will not have.

I'd like to ask to experienced users about Jenkins, is it still worth to use Jenkins for central build&management of the project ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even for simple projects a continuous integration environment is useful. For one, it helps developers verify they have committed all their changes and have not forgot any changes that would break the build.

Along those lines, its also to have a single location from which to build and grab artifacts to deploy. Using developer systems for this always has the potential for introducing errors do to environmental changes between developers such as JDK versions, etc.

Comment: Where I work we have a large project that takes a while to build and run all 8000 tests.  We recently created a new build that does compile only and fires more often so we avoid the lengthy build with tests when the compile is going to fail anyway. So yes, it can be worth it even without tests. As a developer, it's nice to have validation that the build was broken before my changes and not because of my changes.